# Resolve Explorer Address to File Path

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

In Explorer If you click on many of the Quick Access folders you get something like "This PC > Downloads" or "OneDrive". I know how to manually find those locations, but I'm wondering if there is a quick way to simply convert that to a file/UNC path. I half expect that I can right click on the address bar, or in the left "Quick Access" bar in Explorer and choose "Open Folder Location" like I can do when looking at the properties of a shortcut, but that doesn't work.

Comment: If you right-click and go to Properties, it should say the the parent path as "Location". What are you seeing exactly? As far as UNC, that would only work if your c$ administrative share is enabled or you have manually created a share

Comment: @InterLinked, try that on a OneDrive folder. And that doesn't work from the address bar even for "This PC > Downloads"

Comment: I don't use OneDrive and it doesn't show up there. But I tried it with downloads and I get a path of format "C:\Users\%username%" as "Location". What are you getting?

Comment: I get the same thing, but that is 3 clicks and another window, and I can't tell someone to always do that because it only works for certain folders; it doesn't work for all folders pinned to "Quick access".

Comment: It works for every folder there for me - Desktop, Downloads, and Documents. I don't think there's an easier way to do it. What folder does this *not* work for?

Comment: Now that I look closer, all the ones it doesn't work for me are folder in OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Explorer is hard-coded to favor a namespace path over the file system source when it has to choose. I don't think you can battle that very easily, but here's a .reg file that adds a "Open File Location" to directories and all files.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open File Location]
@="&Open File Location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open File Location\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" /select,\"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open File Location]
@="&Open File Location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open File Location\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" /select,\"%1\""
```